# Generic DataGrid for editing objects stored on a server

Tags: java, apache-flex, blazeds

I've knocked together a Java/BlazeDS server which creates a generic GridBean object. This GridBean contains:

- `List<ColumnDef>` where a ColumnDef contains the column header, field name
- `List<Object>` where my object is some java pojo containing `PropertyChangeSupport`

I then created a Flex app that uses a `RemoteObjectServiceWrapper` to call my java server, grab the `GridBean`, create some `DataGrid` columns from the `columnDefs` and then set the `dataProvider` as the list of objects. Ok so far, everything renders.

Now, what I'd really like to do is: set up some kind of event handler on the flex side so that if my item/object is edited in the datagrid, I fire a message off to java saying 'edited this field on this item'. The end goal is to have a nice generic way to render any list of objects from Java in a flex datagrid.

Comment: Show some code.  Also, I think you meant you "Mocked up a Java/BlazeDS Server"; perhaps?  Knocked up is slag for getting someone pregnant in the US.

Comment: Also, when you add some code, you may want to re-work this to actually ask a question.  I voted to close.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com I think you mean "Slang".  In Australia, a "Slag" is exactly the type of person you wouldn't want to get pregnant.

Comment: @Marty Pitt Right you are!  That was my typo.

Answer (score 0):

Effectively you're talking about ManagedObjects, which are not supported natively in BlazeDS.  (It's available as an out-of-the-box feature of LCDS).

However, there are 3rd party tools which give you this functionality.

Farata systems offers [Clear Builder](http://flexblog.faratasystems.com/2010/08/26/new-clear-data-builder-4-0-doc) (which I believe offers CRUD support via generated code).

There's also [dpHibernate](http://code.google.com/p/dphibernate/) (which I should disclose I'm one of the main developers of).

Using dpHibernate, what you're after is achievable like so:

```
public function updateObject():void
{
     var book:Book; // loaded from the server earlier in the application
     book.title = "Clean Code";
     book.save();
}
```

Your entity class (in this example, `Book`) is only required to implement a couple of simple interface methods (which deal primarily with the concept of identity), and does not require any generated code.

There's a pretty complete working example of this update functionality available [here](http://code.google.com/p/lazyoverflow/).

Comment: Looks nice Marty. Using dpHibernate, you're required to mirror each java bean as an AS bean I presume? I guess it's not too much of an issue with code generation though.

Comment: @Berti - Correct, although you should be doing this anyway, as it's really best practice.  I'd reccommend taking a look at the excellent dto2fx by faratta systems for auto generation of AS entities from their java counterparts.